# google analytics events for uicollectionview cell in ios

Tags: ios, google-analytics, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view in my app. I want to put google analytics events for each collection view cell. That meant ,as an example when user taps on a cell, google analycis event should trigger. I have implement google analytics for screens(for main screen).stiil I do not have permission to attach images.

this is my code.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CategoryCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionreuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell addSubview:cell.categorylabel];
//    [cell addSubview:cell.imageWebView];

Attachments *attch = [attachments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.categorylabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@  ", attch.attachmenttitle];
[cell.categorylabel sizeToFit];
 //    [cell.imageWebView loadRequest:attch.request];

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body{padding:0; margin:0;}</style></head><body><img src='%@' width='800' height='800'></body></html>",attch.imageurl];
[cell.imageWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[self.tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"categories" action:attch.attachmenttitle label:attch.attachmenttitle value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]] build]];



return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the `analytics` action to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

remove the following line from `cellForItemAtIndexPath` here

```
  self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[self.tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"categories" action:attch.attachmenttitle label:attch.attachmenttitle value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]] build]];
```

add the line to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
 - (void)tableView:(UICollectionView *)tableView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 NSArray*cells = [mainTable visibleCells];

UITableViewCell *currentcell = [mainTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
for (UITableViewCell*cell in cells)
{
    if ([cell isEqual:currentcell] == NO) 
     {

       }
    else
    {
       self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[self.tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"categories" action:attch.attachmenttitle label:attch.attachmenttitle value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]] build]];
     }

}



}
```

Comment: if user press the any items the tracker handle your action

Comment: thanx Anbu.Karthik @A it works, but there is a small problem. when I tap a cell it works and show in google analytics events. when I go back and tap another cell google analytics shows both are active. Is there a way to fix this. thanx again.

Comment: @anuk  -- actually Google analytics event capture us how many times you handle the particular event , as your want if you select the same cell again don't send the event tracker to analytics correct

Comment: Anbu.Karthik, sorry for the delay. the answer is working and fine. thanx again

Comment: yes, I knew it , but I do not have enough reputations to vote up, sorry for that and I will do whenever  it is possible.

Comment: have a nice day bro , happy day bye

Answer (score 0):

`cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called each time cell is about to be presented ot screen(for example if it was not visible and user scrolled or when initial load of collection view). If you want to track when user taps on cell you need to call GAI method inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the same code of Screen Tracking & replace it with you required values in the `CollectionView` Delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UICollectionView *)tableView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// Your Google Analytics code 
}
```